# QProcess can't fire sigal readyRead/readyReadStandardOutput/readyReadStandardError

Tags: c++, qt

Why do I never get readyRead/readyReadStandardOutput/readyReadStandardError signal when I run the following? i get all the output in the console.i am working with a Qt4.8 application to call a child process in lubuntu 16.04 64bit.This problem has been bothering me for a long time.I used to try the same code on win7 and it worked perfectly.

mainwindow header file :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        QProcess* process;
    private slots:
        void on_pushButton_clicked();
        void OnRead();
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow source :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = new QProcess(this);
    bool result = connect(process, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(OnRead()));
    qDebug() << result;
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(OnRead()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(OnRead()));
    process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
    process->start("/home/albert/test");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
}
void MainWindow::OnRead()
{
    qDebug() << "can read";
}
```

test code is here:

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> /* Definition of uint64_t */
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        std::cout << "hello world!0";
        printf("hello world!\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "hello world error!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you have `setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels)`.  The standard output and error of the child process will be forwarded to the standard output and error of the parent process.

Comment: thank you.removed setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels),it works!

Comment: when i use `qDebug()<<process->readAllStandardOutput()`,i can get the standard out of child process,but the standard out was printed with quotation marks.I expect to get `hello world` but get `"hello word"`.Why？

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, the use of `setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels)` causes the following [behaviour](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum)...

> QProcess forwards the output of the running process onto the main
>   process. Anything the child process writes to its standard output and
>   standard error will be written to the standard output and standard
>   error of the main process.

As to why this might have generated the various `readyRead*` signals on Windows I can only guess that if the parent process didn't actually have any console associated with it (e.g. GUI process) then the call to `setProcessChannelMode` would be ignored leaving you with the default channel mode of `QProcess::SeparateChannels`.

Regarding the extra double quotes in the output, that's just what `qDebug` does for certain types such as [`QByteArray`, `QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-20) etc.  If you want to remove the quotes try...

```
qDebug().noquote() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
```